# jQuery equivalent for C#

Tags: c#, jquery

Is there a jQuery equivalent for C#? Basically, I want to download some html from a site and parse it the same way jQuery works. I realize that .Net has its own xml parser but it's not the same thing.

Comment: jQuery is a large framework, capable of doing hundreds of things from DOM manipulation to AJAX to animation. Which feature of jQuery do you want to use in C#

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you want to parse and do with it?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic, but [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) is a nice library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a library called Html Agility Pack: http://html-agility-pack.net

You can parse HTML and then select nodes, and work them... not the same as jQuery but it is a very near match.

One major benefit of HAP is, it will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM, so is very useful for the HTML you find in the wild.

Comment: yes it is the best tool ever

Comment: Yeap! It is a standard now, there is plenty of support from community and it has passed the test of many production environments.